# Cannot assign true to scoped var if it's binded to a datepicker-popup

Tags: angularjs, datepicker, angular-ui-bootstrap

I have two boolean variables in the scope `foo` and `bar`, both set to `false`.

I have created 2 buttons for each one to set their value `true` or `false` but, if the variable is bound to the property `is-open` of a `datepicker-popup`, then it cannot be setted to true.

Can anybody tell me what's wrong?

Here is a [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/VYU3Z0nYqaJK3N9XUguH?p=preview) with the case.

Comment: What version are you using?

Comment: You can see it in the plunker: angular 1.4.2, ui-bootstrap 0.13.0, bootstrap-css 3.3.1

Answer (score 0):

"`The issue relates to the fact the the datepicker directive uses the ngModelController but has an isolated scope to support the dateDisabled attribute, which means you can only set the ngModel on the parent element and not on the datepicker element.`"

As seen [here](https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/issues/784) on Github on the Angular UI Bootstrap Repo

Here is your demo in what seems to me like now working condition based on the repo feedback and "fix": http://plnkr.co/edit/DA1E9RlE8gYBpgc39eH0?p=preview

I applied the ng-model to the parent node which in this case is your `<body>` element

**Here is a screenshot of it working:**

[image]

Comment: Also as an author of the framework describes the solution to this in a similar fashion: http://plnkr.co/edit/EFYBUuDt23U3wHvsD2rG?p=info

Comment: Why the down vote with no explanation coward! My answer is correct, as the OP has the ng-model on a datepicker directive.

Comment: Sorry wasn't me who down vote but, with your solution `bar` value changes in scope but datepicker does not open.

Comment: It works fine! I just tested it I am adding a screen shot of it now

Comment: Can you ellaborate on 'not open'? @ Esteve

Comment: I want to show the calendar popup when `bar` is true, and switch on/off using an external button. The screenshot you added is not from `ui.bootstrap` calendar, it's rendered by Chrome and only works in that browser. Firefox, for example, does not provide it.

Comment: your popup is provided by Chrome, please change `intput type='date'` to `intput type='text'`to disable it and let ui-bootstrap popup to be shown.